# Magento: Build custom product collection of all configurable products in stock

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to build a product collection of all configurable products which are 'in-stock' or 'is-saleable'. These require two different models to be used. My working method is:

```
$collectionConfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));

foreach ($collectionConfigurable as $_configurableproduct) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_configurableproduct->getId());

    if ($product->isSaleable()) { 
// do something
}
}
```

However this script is REALLY slow and I have a feeling it's wasting resources running as it will be loading and going through EVERY configurable product.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the $collectionConfigurable and make it in-stock items only.

Another resource cites this as a method to get in stock items.

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
```

But I'm not sure how to combine them or use it properly, I've tried this:

```
$collectionConfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));
$instockConfigs = Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collectionconfigurable);
```

This returns with the following error:

```
  Fatal error: Call to a member function joinField() on a non-object in /srv/magento/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Stock.php on line 197
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My "naive to the finer details of the stock system" approach would be to

1. Create a stock item collection, grabbing only the in stock items.
2. Use that collection to create an array of instock product IDs
3. Create a product collection with the configurable filter, as well as an entity_id filter using the collected product IDs

The code for that would look like this.

```
//create a stock item collection with a `is_in_stock` filter
$collection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock')
->getItemCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock');

//capture the product ids of the in stock stock items
$product_ids = array();
foreach($collection as $item)
{
    $product_ids[] = $item->getProductId();
}

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=>$product_ids))
->addFieldToFilter('type_id','configurable');

foreach($products as $product)
{
    var_dump($product->getData());
}
```

That said, your code is slow, in part, because you're reloading each product inside the loop, generating a new series of SQL statements

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_configurableproduct->getId());
```

Also, the `addInStockFilterToCollection` only works with a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Link_Product_Collection` collection.  Take a look at the doc block on the method.

```
/**
 * Adds filtering for collection to return only in stock products
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Link_Product_Collection $collection
 * @return Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock $this
 */
public function addInStockFilterToCollection($collection)
{
    $this->getResource()->setInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Shame they didn't type hint that ([though they may have in newer versions](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_CatalogInventory/Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock.html#addInStockFilterToCollection))

Comment: @SteveRobbins Conventional wisdom has it that type hints come with performance overhead, especially in the older version of PHP (5.2) target by Magento. It's easy to see why a team delivering an app meant for wide deployment would drop the type hints in favor of docblock hinting.